# Enum declared within super class not accessible in sub class

Tags: java, enums

Code is as follows :

```
public class CreateAndUpdateTaxRates {

    public enum WIDGETS {
        RULE_TEMPLATE(0), INSTRUMENT(1), SECURITY_TYPE(2), SECURITY(3), SECURITY_CLASSIFICATION(4), POSITION(5), CLIENT_CLASSIFICATION(6);

        private int widgetNo;

        private WIDGETS(int widgetNo) {
            this.widgetNo = widgetNo;
        }

        public void setWidgetNo(int widgetNo) {
            this.widgetNo = widgetNo;
        }

        public int getWidgetNo() {
            return widgetNo;
        }
    }

public class CreateAndUpdateCATaxCountryDocumentedRates extends CreateAndUpdateTaxRates {

}
```

Want to access enum in subclass CreateAndUpdateCATaxCountryDocumentedRates. How can that be accessed? Once it would be accessed then I need to set the value of enum accordingly in sub classes. For eg. RULE_TEMPLATE is having widget no as 0. I want to change it as 2 from sub class.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why does your enum have a setter?

Comment: This question smells like bad design. Why would you want to change the value of an Enum ? Why is it contained in a class as an inner enum?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I am bit new to enum. Can you please suggest how should I design this to achieve the expected results.

Comment: @vandench because I want to change widgetno property of enum const from subclass

Comment: @ChinmayPareek Normally, an enum should contain static values that don't change. Let's say, colors, states, planets, etc... Here, if you need dynamically changeable values, you better treat this like a class, create objects and have default values set for example.